# set p3p header in html or using javascripts

Tags: java, javascript, html, internet-explorer, p3p

there are site A and B  which communicate Using easyXDM

i try to set cookies of site B using site A chrome and mozilla allow to set cookies but ie not allow to set cookie some security polices

for which site have to set p3p header ?

```
<meta http-equiv="P3P" content='CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA"'>
```

i set header in html but then also not able to set cookie

Answer (score 0):

you would set the P3P in your main page that revives cookies for a different domain

to set a header for `p3p` for a jsp you could do it like this

```
response.setHeader("P3P","CP='IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA'")
```

Comment: my project under tomcat my ajax request and set cookies function on another page not on index page and how to set p3p